# How do I get my first_name input to work as well as have the user input only the correct coffee order choices within the loop inside my Python 3 code?

Tags: python-3.x

Question 1: I am not sure how to get first_name to display on lines 27-28. What code do I add?

Question 2: I want the input for lines 27-28 with the question "What type of Coffee would you like today?" to be bypassed using only the correct coffee types of ["Expresso", "Latte", "Cappuccino", "Mocha", "Frappuccino"] with a loop containing "break" to pass to next question and "continue" to retry if the user input did not choose from 1 or more coffee types and in which they can also include the word "and" and comma "," for correct input like "Expresso and Latte" or "Expresso Latte" or "Expresso, Latte and Mocha" or even "Expresso Latte Mocha", all which still allow comma's, "and" and 5 coffee type choices ONLY to bypass to the next question.
What code do I need to add?

Code

```py
company_name = "Daniel's Coffee"


def greet():
    print("\n" + "Hello" + "!" + " " + "Welcome to" + " " + company_name + "!" + "\n")


greet()


def name():
    while True:
        first_name = input("Can I start off with your first name?" + "\n\n")
        if len(first_name) >= 3:
            print("\n" + "Thank you," + " " + first_name.capitalize() + "!")
            break
        else:
            print("\n" + "Invalid input," + " " + "please try again" + "!" + "\n")
        continue


name()


def coffee_order():
    while True:
        order = input("\n" + first_name + "What type of Coffee would you like today?" +
                      "\n\n"
                      + "\n".join(["Expresso", "Latte", "Cappuccino", "Mocha",
                                   "Frappuccino"]) + "\n\n")

        order = order.replace("and a", "")
        order = order.replace("and", "")
        order = order.replace(",", "")
        order = order.lower().split()
        union = " and a " if len(order) > 1 else ""
        plural = "" if len(order) > 1 else ""

        if order:
            order = input("\n" + "You have selected a" + " " + ", ".join(order[:-1]).title()
                          + union + plural +
                          order[-1].title() + "!" + " " + "\n\n" + "Is that correct?" +
                          "\n\n")
        if order.capitalize() == "Yes":
            print("\n" + "Wonderful" + "!")
            break
        elif order.capitalize() == "No":
            continue
        else:
            print("Invalid input, please try again" + "!")
            continue


coffee_order()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For the first name to be available you need to provide it as an argument to `coffee_order` or have a global variable defined outside and then accessed inside the function using `global first_name` before usage.

A much better approach would be to group these attributes and functions in a class. Below I have provided a template for this to help you experiment and use it for your project:

```
class CoffeeShop:
    """Coffee shop class."""

    COFFEE_TYPES = ["Expresso", "Latte", "Cappuccino", "Mocha", "Frappuccino"]

    def __init__(self):
        self.company_name = "Daniel's Coffee"
        self.first_name = None

    def greet(self):
        """Print greeting."""
        print(f"Hello! Welcome to {self.company_name}!")

    def get_name(self):
        """Get customer first name."""
        while True:
            self.first_name = input("Can I start off with your first name?\n")
            if len(self.first_name) >= 3:
                print(f"Thank you {self.first_name}!")
                return

            print("You must enter at least 3 characters!\n")

    def coffee_order(self):
        """Process coffee order."""
        while True:
            order = input(f"{self.first_name}, what coffee would you like today?\n "
                          f"Available coffee types are : {CoffeeShop.COFFEE_TYPES}\n")

            if order in CoffeeShop.COFFEE_TYPES:
                print(f"You have selected {order}. Thank you!")
                return

            print(f"{order} is not currently available.\n Please chose one of following: {CoffeeShop.COFFEE_TYPES}")


coffee_shop = CoffeeShop()

coffee_shop.greet()
coffee_shop.get_name()
coffee_shop.coffee_order()
```

Comment: How do I provide an argument to coffee_order in order for first_name to become available?

Comment: Modify  `name()` function to `return first_name`. Update `coffee_order` definition to accept an argument: `def coffee_order(first_name)`. When you call the function, you can call it like this: `coffee_order(name())`